# Migrating from umbraco 4 to umbraco 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

We have project on Umbraco 4 (web forms). And now we want to use Umbraco 5. Is there a way to migrate site from v4 to v5 ( and replace asp.net projects with user controls to mvc3 projects with partial razor views or something like this) In solution i have many Class libraries and asp.net projects with user controls and web services.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umbraco has specifically stated there is no upgrade path from v4 to v5.  They basically say if you want to go to v5, it should be time to do a rewrite on your application anyways.

See this article for more information:

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/11/14/the-upgrade-myth.aspx

> A frequent topic we meet as we approach the release of Umbraco 5 is
>   "how can I upgrade to Umbraco 5 [from Umbraco 4]". The answer is
>   simple - you can't. But what's even more interesting is - you wouldn't
>   even if you could. What you worry about is irrelevant - it's what I
>   call "The Upgrade Myth".

Answer (score 8):

Might be worth to point out here that active development on Umbraco V5 has ended. There's more information on their blog: [link](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The migration path from v4 to v5 is irrelevant now because [Umbraco scrapped version 5](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx) last week.  But there are already ideas out there on how to [run Umbraco 4 with MVC](http://www.aaron-powell.com/umbraco/using-mvc-in-umbraco-4).

Answer (score 2):

Anyone interested in Umbraco 5 should checkout RebelCMS.  It's a fork of Umbraco 5 and it is very promising:

http://www.rebelcms.com/

Answer (score 0):

From the latest news I have there will be a free version of Umbraco Contour which can migrate the content from a v4 installation to a v5 installation. As I know this will not affect the document types, templates and macros, only the content.